# Azure Pipeline Release Artefact linked ARM templates

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-rm-template, azure-releases

We have our ARM templates in a `build` folder alongside our code. In our **pipeline** we publish our `build` folder as an artefact. We have master templates.

We want to run our ARM templates from a Release Pipeline, however our master templates can't find our linked templates, we get the following errors:

> ##[error]InvalidTemplateSpec: The relative path 'arm-kv/1.0.0.0/azuredeploy.json' could not be resolved.  Please ensure the parent deployment references either an external URI or a template spec ID.  The relativePath property cannot be used when creating a template deployment with a local file.

The folder structure of the created artefact is as follows;

```
Builds/
+-- ARM/
     +-- parameters/
     |   +-- azuredeploy-rg-parameters.json  ## parameters file
     |
     +-- arm-kv
     |   +-- 1.0.0.0/
     |       +-- azuredeploy.json   ##(linked key vault template)
     |
     |- arm-storage
     |   +-- 1.0.0.0/
     |       +-- azuredeploy.json   ##(linked storage template)
     |
     +-- azuredeploy-rg.json   ##(main template)
```

What is the correct syntax for referencing the subfolder/templates? We've tried

- `arm-kv/1.0.0.0/azuredeploy.json` (relative path)
- `./arm-kv/1.0.0.0/azuredeploy.json`
- `/builds/arm/arm-kv/1.0.0.0/azuredeploy.json` (the full artefact path)

Answer (score 0):

When you run the task you are probably in the `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` context. This is the folder where artifacts are downloaded. Please check what you have exacelty there by adding a step and listing files.

Once you have it change your working directory for your ARM deployment step to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/builds/arm` (it could be slightly different and this is why former step is needed to verify the path). Once you set it correctly you will get `azuredeploy-rg.json` in the root and all linked templates will become discoverable.